# sql statement with not null in as3

Tags: sqlite, actionscript-3, air

Am trying to pass a not null value to sqlite parameter in as3 in adobe air for desktop,
here is the sample of code:

```
stat.text = "SELECT * FROM people, WHERE gender = @gender AND year = @year AND month = @month";
stat.parameters["@gender"] = genderBox.value;
stat.parameters["@year"] = year.text;
stat.parameters["@month1"] = month.text;
```

where genderBox is a combobox with 2 values of course male and female and the others are just textboxes. i want to make the genderBox having 3 values the third one is Both males and females so when the user select both the statment select both the males and females i want it to pass something like not null value and select everything from that column but choose the other columns month and year

Comment: So you want to run the query without the `WHERE gender = @gender`? Why don't you do exactly that?

Comment: @CL. Well I can't delete that because sometimes I want the user to select one gender only not both and sometimes all the records

Answer (score 2):

Why not create statement in two steps?

```
stat.text = "SELECT * FROM people WHERE year = @year AND month = @month";
if (genderBox.value) {
   stat.text += " AND gender=@gender";
   stat.parameters["@gender"] = genderBox.value;
}
```

I don't know if stat.text can be appended this way but I think the idea is clear.

If you still want to keep it in one piece, change the equality to non-equality like this:

```
stat.text = "SELECT * FROM people WHERE gender != @gender AND year = @year AND month = @month";
```

The logic of using the param @gender will also reverse. If your genderBox returns "male", the query will search all females. If it returns "female", it will search males. To search all, simply pass a non-existing value. So this will require change in the genderBox logic and it will become confusing. So it's not a good way, actually.

UPDATE

If you can make the combobox return a comma-separated list like "male, female" as a third value, you can use the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM people WHERE gender in(@gender)... etc
```

Comment: Thank you I think the first option is the best it even seems to work in other values when there is more than those two like their work or anything else but didn't try it yet so I'll try any give you my result. <br> the second solution is good and maybe I'll try it if the first one won't work but about the third one I can not understand it fully

Comment: the third solution is standard SQL syntax: "where gender in(1,2,3...)" means it will search everything that match any value from the list. So your combobox should return "male", "female" or "male, female".